# IRC client active users in past 15 minutes

Tags: php, irc

I'm trying to find out to to display the active users in the past 15 minutes. Not all the users in the chatroom. Can this be displayed in PHP possibly?

I honestly know nothing about it. The owner of the game I play is trying to do this. Just trying to help him. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could reasonably achieve this if you have either extensive logging on the channel or some kind of bot in the channel which tracks users. Either way, PHP would only be responsible for parsing out the logs in order to identify active users. An IRC channel does not specifically track this information itself.

Comment: So, it doesn't know who's active I suppose?

Comment: You can certainly query for current users by connecting to the channel as a client. Also, you may be able to identify idle users (depending on the server modes); but you won't be able to see activity in a certain time frame without some additional metrics.